# Identifying Features With a Relationship Class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, relationship-class

I have a feature class which represents points where vegetation clearing has occurred.  I also have a table which has a list of vegetation species which were cleared at each location and the amount of vegetation which was in the sampled area.  I have a relationship class in the geodatabase which links the two based on a `Clearing_ID` field.

When the user clicks on a point with the Identify tool, they can drill down to see the list of plant species present.  However, the list appears as numbers which is the `OBJECTID`.  Ideally, I'd like the user to see the list of species present as the default field instead of the object ID.

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open table properties by right-clicking on the tablename in the
   table of contents.
2. In the Display tab, change the field to 'Plant_Species_Present'

Comment: That works if the Plant_Species_Present table is open in the Table of Contents.  However, the user will probably have the Clearing Location feature class open, which is related to the Plant_Species_Present table. If the Plant_Species_Present table isn't open, it defaults to OBJECTID.

Answer (score 5):

1. As described in [another answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/43473), under Properties set the Display tab default to the field you are wanting to use.
2. Then with the Identify tool, select the related features again.
3. Highlight what you are wanting to change, right click and chose "Show Relates With Field Properties".

Note: this changes the Relationship Labels as well but at least you can now see the name of the plant species.

[image]